# Prove x and p are coprime

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let $x$ be an even integer and p=$x^{4}+1$.

$p$ being a prime divisor

How can I prove that $x$ and $p$ are co-prime to one another.

Also that $x$ is invertible modulo $p$.

Would I assume $\gcd(x,p)=1$, then prove by a proof by contradiction?

Comment: sorry with x being an even integer and p=$x^{4}+1$ p being a prime divisor

Comment: We just want to show that $p$ cannot divide $x$. It it did, it would divide $x^4$, so it would divide $(x^4+1)-x^4$, which is $1$.

Comment: "Invertible modulo $p$" is imediate: $x\cdot (-x^3)\equiv 1\pmod p$.

Comment: So i can use that $(x^{4}+1)-x^{4}$ and that shows they are co-prime. Use Bezouts Identity and show there exists a,b in $Z_{p}$ such that $1=a.x + b.p$ so x has an inverse mod p.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are saying p is a prime divisor.  A prime divisor of what?  Not x as p (which is x^4 + 1) doesn't divide x.  To prove p and x are coprime p doesn't have to be prime.  Andre Nicolas' comment does it.  And there's nothing special about 4 either.   If p = nx + 1 then gcd(x,p) = 1.  p = x^4 + 1 is just the case when n = x^3.

Answer (score 0):

For any integers
$x$ and $n$
with $x \ge 2$
and $n \ge 1$,
$x$ and
$x^n+1$
are co-prime.

Proof:
Suppose $m$ divides
both $x$ and
$x^n+1$.
Then
$m$ divides $x^n$,
so $m$ divides
$(x^n+1)-x^n
=1
$.
Therefore
$m = 1$,
so the two
are co-prime.

If you want to use
Bezout's identity,
just do this:

$1 \cdot (x^n+1)-(x^{n-1})x
= 1
$.

Comment: assume $(p,x) \neq 1$ $\rightarrow x=\mu p ,\mu \in Z$ 
$\rightarrow x^{4}=\mu^{4}p^{4}$, then $x^{4}+1=\mu^{4}p^{4}+1$
clearly p does not divide $x^{4}+1$  but we know that p is a prime divisor of $x^{4}+1$ thus there is a contradiction and $(p,x)=1$. is this right?

Comment: Right, but you do not need that $p$ is a prime divisor of $x$, only a divisor of $x$.